# input string was not in correct format in c# while posting data in textbox

Tags: c#

I am getting an error saying the input string was not in correct format. I have also converted my variables to int. Here is my code. Kindly let me know where I went wrong.

```
private void CashTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    int total = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
      .Sum(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells[1].Value));

    int cashtotal = Convert.ToInt32(CashTextBox.Text);

    // TotalTextBox.Text = total + cashtotal;

    int i = total + cashtotal;
    TotalTextBox.Text = i.ToString();
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `cashtotal` (as well as `total`) an *integer* (`int cashtotal = ..`)? Shouldn't it be `decimal` (or `double`)?

Comment: Firstly welcome to stackoverflow, adding code was a great step, usually you want to paste your error message too. however, your tip for the day is use `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're trying to convert text values into integers.  What *are* those text values?

Comment: are the values in `CashTextBox.Text` or `t.Cells[1]` numbers at all?

Comment: I would go with the `TryParse`, as earlier mentioned. To that - you might consider using a named convention for the `t.cell["aName"]`  - since changes can occur in you `datagrid`.

Comment: Does every `t.Cells[1].Value` produce a string that is convertible to an int? Same for `CashTextBox.Text`? Both empty string `""` and `null` will produce the error that you are getting.

Comment: @Halex: The question is about **converting a string to an int**, not the other way around. Secondly, `int.TryParse()` is a possible approach, but so is `Convert.ToInt32()`. Your comment implies that the latter should not be used; which is a claim that I see no justification for.

Answer (score 0):

You must check dataType before convert data.

```
 int.TryParse(CashTextBox.Text, out var cashtotal); //C# 7.0
```

or

```
 int cashtotal;
 int.TryParse(CashTextBox.Text, out cashtotal);  //older C# version
```

aslo here :

```
.Sum(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells[1].Value));
```